Styling X apps resources
In the following question: X apps without menu right and bottom border.
A solution is found using the X resource displayList. I've searched in various places about the format of this resource, but I was not able to find any description.
Does anyone know the format specification or any place I can find the description?

xfontsel uses the X Athena Widget Set (Xaw). The resource displayList is described in detail in the "DISPLAY LISTS" section of the Xaw(3) manpage.
